# Print the environment map for Gradle test task

Tags: java, testing, gradle

With Java plugin test task in Gradle, how can I print the environment map for the JVM process which executes the tests.

```
test.doFirst {
        environment 'KAFKA_PORT', "${KAFKA_TCP_9902}"
        environment 'DB_PORT', "${MYSQL_TCP_3306}"
        // How to print the map of all environments set so far?
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access the `environment` map directly. Just loop through it and print the values over the keys:

```
test.doFirst {
    [...] // do something
    environment.each { k, v -> println "${k}:${v}" }
}
```

Both the [map property](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:environment) and [two methods to add values](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:environment(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)), one of them you use, are named `environment`. By default, the environment variables from the Gradle process are used.

Comment: Thanks, it was actually intuitive. Not sure, why it did not hit me.